# Runtime Error: Found no NVIDIA driver on your system

Tags: gpu, cpu, torch, huggingface-transformers, seq2seq

I am facing issue while loading the model using torch which was trained using GPU, I am trying to load that model using CPU. however I am successfully able to load the model but while predicting the results I am getting error. However if I use GPU machine I am able to predict the output but not on the CPU:

My code:

```py
****To save the model I am using :****
PATH = "model.pt"
torch.save(model, PATH)

**To Load the Model**


 import torch
    PATH = "model.pt"
    device = torch.device('cpu')
    loaded_model=torch.load(PATH, map_location=device)
```

I am able to successfully load the model. but while predicting I am getting runtime error

```py
**Predicting the loaded model using CPU**
predicted_title = loaded_model.predict([abstract])
```

> Runtime Error: Found no NVIDIA driver on your system. Please check that you have an NVIDIA GPU and installed a driver

I am sorry if the error might turn out very simple but I am not able to rectify this.

Comment: Well according to the [documentation](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/saving_loading_models.html#save-on-gpu-load-on-cpu) this should work. Can you verify if the the abstract is also on CPU device?

Answer (score 0):

You can output the models device with

```py
print(loaded_model.device)
```

if it is not cpu, do

```py
model = model.to('cpu')
```